# Workflow in a document library - SP Foundation

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I am really struggling with Foundation and its limitations. In the past I have used enterprise which is much easier!

My problem is that I need to create a document library which will hold expenditure request forms. I have created a form template in Word 2007 as it holds the server properties and can populate the list columns. I need a workflow that will kick off once a file is uploaded to the list and email the first approver. Once they have approved it i will be using a second workflow to go to the next approval level etc. My main problem is i have never had to create a workflow before!

I managed to create stage one but it will not initiate automatically. I cant find any tutorials on the web and I have looked everywhere I can think of.

Thing is am I going about the whole thing correctly or should I be using a form library and an infopath form? If i went down that route do people need infopath to be able to complete the form or will it open on any machine?

So I guess in summery my questions are:

- Which is the best library type and template type for this kind of
  document?
- How do i get a workflow to initiate automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you created the Workflow with SharePoint Designer 2010. In such case, every workflow, on the Workflow Page have an Workflow Settings page (see here http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/workflow-settings-in-sharepoint-2010.html) but you could also use direclty SPD to change the way the workflow launches: Manually, Upon Item Creation or Item Update (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/415107/Create-a-Workflow-using-SharePoint-Designer)

Besides, it is also important to decide how your workflow is attached, it could be a LIST Workflow - directly  attaches to a list, or Reusable (attaches to a Content Types, e.g. All DOcuments), or Site Workflow (more complicated, not suitable for you).

Generally, start here for a quick reference on various activities http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx

Comment: Thanks I shall have a look through the links. Yes it is created in Designer 2010 and I have done it as a list workflow.